# How to use "directories are the same" in a conditional in Unix Bash Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, conditional-statements, rsync

I want to compare two directories in a conditional.

```
if [ rsync -ai --dry-run dir1/ dir2/ ]; then
  echo "Different!"
fi
```

However, I'm getting an error.\

> ./test.sh: line 44: [: too many arguments

How do I fix this error and get the conditional to echo if and only if the directories are different?

Note, `rsync` works as expected without the conditional.

```
rsync -ai --dry-run dir1/ dir2/
```

returns null when dir1 and dir2 are the same. And a non-null value otherwise.

Comment: You can shorten your `rsync` command while including `--update` and `--dry-run` (with their short forms) as `rsync -uain dir1/ dir2`. With a conditional, you could combine with `wc -l`, e.g. `if [ $(rsync -uain dir1/ dir2 | wc -l) -gt '0' ]; then ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What goes in `[ ]` is a test expression, not a command. Something like `[ 5 -gt 4 ]` or `[ "foo" = "bar" ]`. That rsync command doesn't make any sense as an expression, so you get a (not terribly clear) error.

It's possible capture the output of a command with `"$( )"`, and test to see if that's blank with the `-n` test operator: `if [ -n "$(rsync ...)" ]`, but there's actually a better way here. What goes after `if` is itself a command. `[` is a really common command to use there, but you can use any command (or pipeline, or whatever) there. Essentially, it's "if this command succeeds, then..." So you can do this:

```
if rsync -ai --dry-run dir1/ dir2/ | grep -q "."; then
```

This feeds the output of the `rsync` command to `grep`, searching for "." (a pattern matching any character, i.e. is there *any* output), and the `-q` (quiet) option tells it not to bother printing matches, just exit with success status if there's at least one match.

Comment: It's probably easier to simply check the exit status of `rsync` rather than infer anything from the fact that it wrote to standard output.

Comment: @chepner The exit status of `rsync --dry-run` is not useful for this. It will exit successfully whether or not there are differences (as long as it successfully *checked* for differences).

Comment: You could use `if diff -rq dir1/ dir2/ >/dev/null; then` -- this would do full-file comparisons rather than just looking at size & date for changes.

Answer (score 2):

`[[ -n string ]]` returns true if the length of string is non-zero, so you can do:

```
if [[ -n $(rsync -ai --dry-run dir1/ dir2/) ]]; then
  echo "Different!"
fi
```